# how to save Python pandas data into excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I am trying to load data from the web source and save it as a Excel file but not sure how to do it. What should I do? The original dataframe has different columns. Let's say that I am trying to save 'Open' column

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def ViewStockTrend(compcode):        
    start = datetime.datetime(2015,2,2)
    end = datetime.datetime(2016,7,13)
    stock = web.DataReader(compcode,'yahoo',start,end)    
    print(stock['Open'])


compcode = ['FDX','GOOGL','FB'] 
aa= ViewStockTrend(compcode)
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have made the pandas dataframe just use `to_excel` on the entire thing if you want:

`aa.to_excel('output/filename.xlsx')`

Answer (score 2):

If `stock` is a pandas DataFrame, you need to construct a new Framefrom that column and output that one to excel:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(stock['Open'])
df.to_excel('path/to/your/file')
```